# PHP Android how to dowload apk file

Tags: php, android, download, apk, force-download

I have Android app on my server and also have php code like:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.apk"');
readfile('test.apk');
```

My mobile with default web browser is downloading this file in the way of reading apk file on the screen. I expected some kind of dialogue like: save it as or/and where do you want to save it instead. 
What I am doing wrong?
Is there any way to save it automatically, meaning without any dialogue?

Comment: I think you mean "automatically"...

Comment: @Avyakt what happens if you send `application/zip` as the content type. Since an APK is just a renamed zip archive, this should probably work as expected (if you're giving `.apk` as suggested appendix).

Comment: @LukasKnuth exactly, but even if I did change it the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");    
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.apk"');
readfile('C4A.apk');
```

Comment: It does not help, the mobile browser put content of apk file on screen as it should be read not downloaded. But thank you for suggestion.

Comment: In order to make it works I did change design, php code sends apk via email and it works for now. But, the question is without answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should try one of these:

1. check the mime type configuration on your server. [APK Files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29)
2. [add the apk extension to apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569313/cant-install-apk-hosted-my-own-apache-server)

also, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673008/download-apk-from-own-webserver). However the server is .net, not php.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ad 2, I know this question but I do not know how could I apply these answers into my question. Ad 1, How can I check my server "my provider server" regarding to apk extension?

Comment: @Avyakt as mentioned, you can check on `/etc/mime.types` something like `application/vnd.android.package-archive     apk` and you have to add this `AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive .apk` to `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mime.conf`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with apache  apk extension, because I can download apk file on my PC via Firefox, but I cannot do that via default web browser on my mobile.